# Iptables counters restore, when using quotas, not working as expected

Tags: linux, iptables

I've set a quota for a certain computer:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.10 -m quota --quota 500000000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.10 -j DROP
```

This works as expected. When the limit (500MB) is reached, all packets for this particular computer get dropped.

But, if I save the counters (iptables-save -c > /home/iptables.counters), restart iptables, and restore the counters (iptables-restore -c /home/iptables.counters), then no matter what the saved counters were, that computer will still be able to download 500 MB, so the total counter size, before that computer loses internet access will be X + 500MB, where X is the saved counter size.

I must be doing something wrong, since this is the whole point to saving/restoring counters: resuming from that byte count until the limit is reached. Any type of hint would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: If you inspect the counters after the iptables-restore command are they what you expect ?

Comment: Yes. They are restored properly. But it's as if they're not there. The user is still able to download 500MB.

Comment: Which distro is this on? Which virtualization technology (if any) is your system using ?

Comment: It's a Fedora 20 server running on VMWare VSphere ESXi 5.1.

Comment: This smells like a kernel bug, and I would report it as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem *is* a kernel bug.

In EL6 the quota code that does the matching shows this:

```
quota_mt(const struct sk_buff *skb, const struct xt_match_param *par)
{
        struct xt_quota_info *q = (void *)par->matchinfo;
        struct xt_quota_priv *priv = q->master;
        bool ret = q->flags & XT_QUOTA_INVERT;

        spin_lock_bh(&quota_lock);
        if (priv->quota >= skb->len) {
                priv->quota -= skb->len;
                ret = !ret;
        } else {
                /* we do not allow even small packets from now on */
                priv->quota = 0;
        }
        /* Copy quota back to matchinfo so that iptables can display it */
        q->quota = priv->quota;
        spin_unlock_bh(&quota_lock);

        return ret;
```

In F20 it shows this:

```
static bool
quota_mt(const struct sk_buff *skb, struct xt_action_param *par)
{
  struct xt_quota_info *q = (void *)par->matchinfo;
  struct xt_quota_priv *priv = q->master;
  bool ret = q->flags & XT_QUOTA_INVERT;

  spin_lock_bh(&priv->lock);
  if (priv->quota >= skb->len) {
    priv->quota -= skb->len;
    ret = !ret;
  } else {
    /* we do not allow even small packets from now on */
    priv->quota = 0;
  }
  spin_unlock_bh(&priv->lock);

  return ret;
}
```

Its basically the same (minus spacing changes) **apart** from one line;

```
        /* Copy quota back to matchinfo so that iptables can display it */
        q->quota = priv->quota;
```

This is meant as a display parameter.

So in EL6 if you setup a quota, pass some packets through, then do `iptables -vnL SOMECHAIN` you'll notice the quota value decrements.

In F20 doing the same thing the value doesn't decrement. I guess the designers believe its probably a better thing to make sure people know what quota was set rather than what the quota really is (seeing as packet counts make it clear what is left).

However, this has an unintended effect. When you run `iptables-save` you save the quota value as read via `iptables`. In EL6, if this value reaches 0 it displays 0 to `iptables`. Thus, when you restore, you restore the 0 back into the iptables chain.

With them removing it, this value never decrements and thus you never actually save the quota.

What really needs to happen is the module needs redesigning. There should be a `quota` entry and a `remaining` entry. Remaining should decrement like in EL6 and be what is used to enforce the quota, whereas "quota" should be the actual set value like in F20. This way you get the best of both worlds. A saved state of the quota and a actual description of what quota is set.

You should probably report this to the netfilter team.

Comment: Thank you very much for that thorough answer. I will report the bug ASAP!

Comment: I'm running into similar issues with Centos 6. Installed version iptables v1.4.21 and latest git v1.6.0 still seem to have this issue. Any news on this?