# How to build and update iptables latest version for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, iptables, centos7, make

Due to a bug [(similar to this one)](https://serverfault.com/questions/606043/iptables-counters-restore-when-using-quotas-not-working-as-expected) i'm facing with iptables in Centos 7, I'd like to update the version of iptables.

```
# yum update iptables
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.coreix.net
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirrors.coreix.net
 * updates: mirrors.coreix.net
No packages marked for update
# iptables -V
iptables v1.4.21
```

So I figured I'd update to either the latest [(from their git)](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/) or to the tagged 1.6.0.

I managed to add the libraries needed to get `./autogen.sh` to run, then managed to `./configure --disable-nftables` and `make` and `make install`.

Now i'm not sure how I can run this version to test it, and how to implement it if it works as the default iptables.

Answer (score 1):

How about direct install

```
yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/iptables-1.4.21-33.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Ref: https://pkgs.org/search/?q=iptables

Answer (score 0):

I've found an [online article](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/iptables.html) that was spot on.

If this helps anyone, the steps I took before this article were the following:

```
git clone git://git.netfilter.org/iptables.git
cd iptables
sudo yum install kernel-devel autoconf automake libtool
```

Then the online article I followed does:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr      \
            --sbindir=/sbin    \
            --disable-nftables \
            --enable-libipq    \
            --with-xtlibdir=/lib/xtables &&
make

sudo su

make install &&
ln -sfv ../../sbin/xtables-multi /usr/bin/iptables-xml &&

for file in ip4tc ip6tc ipq iptc xtables
do
  mv -v /usr/lib/lib${file}.so.* /lib &&
  ln -sfv ../../lib/$(readlink /usr/lib/lib${file}.so) /usr/lib/lib${file}.so
done
```

Comment: You actually need to rebuild kernel to enable extended functionality, that you're looking for

Comment: could you point me to the right direction? also, you mean that even though I see v1.6.0 i'm not seeing all the fixes as some are part of the kernel changes?

Comment: @Anubioz, 1.6.0 says that there's no need to rebuild the kernel https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/INSTALL

Comment: I tried this on a stock Ubuntu 18.04 and ended up with broken iptables:

` ~ iptables --help
iptables: symbol lookup error: iptables: undefined symbol: xtables_find_target_revision`

Answer (score 0):

Git source don't have `configure` script in it, better download sources from iptables website

```
wget http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.8.3.tar.bz2
tar -xvf iptables-1.8.3.tar.bz2
cd iptables-1.8.3
```

then follow this instructions http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/iptables.html